# Error formatting the body of a scrapy request

Tags: python, scrapy, request

When I make an scrapy request without formatting the body I get the right results, however, when I format it in order to make a loop I get a 400 error.
This is the body that's not formatted:
`'{"fields":"id,angellist_url,job_roles","limit":25,"offset":0,"form_data":{"must":{"filters":{"founding_or_hq_slug_locations":{"values":["spain"],"execution":"or"}},"execution":"and"},"should":{"filters":{}},"must_not":{"growth_stages":["mature"],"company_type":["service provider","government nonprofit"],"tags":["outside tech"],"company_status":["closed"]}},"keyword":null,"sort":"-last_funding_date"}'`

This is the formatted body:

`'{"fields":"id,angellist_url,job_roles","limit":25,"offset":{offset_items},"form_data":{"must":{"filters":{"founding_or_hq_slug_locations":{"values":["spain"],"execution":"or"}},"execution":"and"},"should":{"filters":{}},"must_not":{"growth_stages":["mature"],"company_type":["service provider","government nonprofit"],"tags":["outside tech"],"company_status":["closed"]}},"keyword":null,"sort":"-last_funding_date"}'`

Then when making the request I use:

`yield scrapy.Request(url = url, headers = headers, body = body.format(offset_items = '0'))`

Comment: Can you give us an example of what is inside `{**offset_items**}` as everything else seems the same? When you say "format" do you mean you serialize the data with json? When you say "make a loop" did you mean you are trying to make a for loop of the data and put it into the `offset items` inside the nested object?

Comment: An example of what's inside offset_items is 0. And yes, what I mean is to loop the data and put it into the offset_items

Answer (score 0):

The two are identical if not for `**offset_items**` in your 'formatted' string which is causing the issue. Scrapy requires a int for the offset.

You're trying to pass the offset kwarg value to the body using `.format()` but using wrong syntax. Best solution is to use an f-string to pass in the value.

You can use something like `difflib` in python to quickly check the difference between the two strings, which will allow you to easily troubleshoot issues like these

Comment: How can I use the f-string to pass the value in this case, with offset_items = 0?